# Why is not the code executed serially in a python for loop

Tags: python

I have the following functionality in a python script:

```
invoke the shell to create some files(it is a split command from the shell)
for f in a folder
    open f and write something

commands..
```

I have seen that when the program goes to commands after the execution of the for loop many files have not been altered correctly. Some yes and some others no, randomly.

Actually before the loop the files are created with a shell command invoked with popen.subprocess. What is happening is that somewhat the for loop is executed when the popen.subprocess  has not been terminated.How can i force the program to start the for loop as soon as the shell command terminates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this:

```
pid=subprocess.Popen(...)//invoke the shell command which creates a bunch of files
pid.wait()//wait until terminates
for f in a folder
     open f and write something
commands..
```

That solved my problem

Comment: In this case, you should use `subprocess.call` if available to your Python version (added in Python 2.5). `subprocess.Popen` is not a blocking command.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not flushed or closed the files, they may not have been written out yet.  The file object will be implicitly closed by the garbage collection, but that may not be occurring soon enough for your usecase.

```
for f in files:
    out = open(f)
    out.write(something)
    out.close()

do_more.stuff()
```

This can be expressed more succinctly with

```
for f in files:
    with open(f) as out:
        out.write(something)

do_more.stuff()
```

so that the close is done implicitly upon leaving the `with` block.

Comment: A far better way to do this is `with open(f) as out`, which closes the file even if exceptions, `return`, `break` or anything else would skip over `out.close`.

Comment: @delnan: Ah yes.  My Python-2.4 background is showing through; gotta work on that.  Though I think the OP should understand the first form, then use the second.

Comment: yes i am closing the files. See the answer which is now updated

Comment: Iraklis: Then you need to show your code, not some vague approximation of it.  And describe exactly what behavior you are seeing.  At this point, your question has completely changed from what it was orginally.